# Tricky XLOOKUP or Index Match across multiple columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I wish to populate '**owned**' column **tab1** with values *from* **tab2** '**assigned**' column
*IF*
**tab2** '**name2**' column *matches* w **tab1** '**name**' column

**Data**

```
tab1

 A       B  
owned   name
        aa11
        bb22
        cc11
    
    
    
    
tab2

 A       B  
name2   assigned
aa11    bob
dddd    sherri
cc11    renee
```

**Desired**

```
tab1    
owned   name
bob     aa11
        bb22
renee   cc11
    
    
    
    
tab2    
name2   assigned
aa11    bob
dddd    sherri
cc11    renee
```

**Doing**

```
=VLOOKUP(@G:G,'Tab2'!A:D,3,FALSE)
```

However, the data is not populating. Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: sorry will update

Comment: it's simply `=Xlookup(@tab1!B:B, tab2!A:A, tab2!B:B, "", 0, 1)`

Comment: Ok thank you @chrisneilsen will try- do I need to have @ symbol there?

Comment: @ is the [implicit intersection](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34) operator.   You don't _have_ to use it, but it can be usefull

Comment: I cannot mark it as an answer because the user replied as a comment @Harun24HR

Comment: =VLOOKUP(@B:B,'Tab2'!A:B,2,FALSE) would be the corrected version of your own formula. You had your VLOOKUP look for the results in the 3rd column from table column A instead of the second.